# Basic React question. why is useEffect needed in this example from the React documentation?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

This example is given in the react documentation to describe the use of useEffect.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Could this not be re-written without using useEffect as below?
Why is useEffect preferred?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = () => {
      setCount(count + 1);
      document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={handleChange}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here:

- Calling a state setter [won't reassign the stateful `const`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) variable in the current render - you need to wait until the *next* render for `count` to be updated, so

  ```
  const handleChange = () => {
      setCount(count + 1);
      document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  }
  ```

  won't work. Your second snippet will result in `You clicked 0 times` after a single click.
- Even if that were possible, when there are multiple places where a state setter may be called, putting something that should happen afterwards after every single one isn't very maintainable - it'd be better to be able to put that code to run afterwards in only *one* place.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I fully understand your second bullet point. For the first one, how come '<p>You clicked {count} times</p>' does update correctly?

Comment: @SamArcher You can think of `setState` functions [as being async](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). If `count` happened to be updated before setting the document title, that was incidental (not guaranteed). If you need to work with an updated value in the same scope as your `setState` call, you should use a different variable than the `state` value.